# How to search data from foreign table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is 3 mysql tables format :

**project_status**

```
psid    p_id  cdid  sid  short_list  res_sent
1       3     112   24   0           0
2       3     113   25   0           1
3       4     114   22   0           1
4       4     115   23   1           0 
5       5     116   26   0           0
```

**contact_details :**

```
cdid   family_name    given_name     department     title    cid
112    xx             xx             xx             xx       1
113    xx             xx             xx             xx       2
114    xx             xx             xx             xx       3
115    xx             xx             xx             xx       4
116    xx             xx             xx             xx       5
```

**company :**

```
cid   company_name
1     xx
2     xx
3     xx
4     xx
5     xx
```

Now, I need to search `cdid` from `project_status` table based on `p_id` and `sid` to show `family_name, given_name, department, title`

So that I am using following query and I get 3 results

```
SELECT
    cd.family_name,
    cd.given_name,
    cd.department,
    cd.title,
    cd.cid,
    ps.*, company.company_name
FROM
    contact_details AS cd
LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON cd.cdid = ps.cdid
LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid
WHERE
    1 = 1
AND ps.sid IN (25, 22)
AND ps.p_id = '3'
ORDER BY
    company.company_name ASC
```

**NOW** again I want to search on **last result data** (which was 3 results) based on **family_name or given_name or department** search string

**For that I am using following query :**

```
SELECT
    cd.family_name,
    cd.given_name,
    cd.department,
    cd.title,
    cd.cid,
    ps.*, company.company_name
FROM
    contact_details AS cd
LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON cd.cdid = ps.cdid
LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid
WHERE
    1 = 1
AND ps.sid IN (25, 22)
AND company.company_name LIKE '%ab%'
OR cd.family_name LIKE '%ab%'
OR cd.given_name LIKE '%ab%'
AND ps.p_id = '3'
GROUP BY
    cd.cdid
ORDER BY
    company.company_name ASC
```

Now it's should not show me more that 3 result because I have 3 result shown on my first query. BUT unfortunately it's showing me more than 3 results from `contact_details table`

Comment: Why `WHERE 1=1` what does that add to the party

Comment: Wrap your `OR` clauses in `()` otherwise they will just cause confusion Currently thay are expanding your search criteria beyond what you think

Comment: @Avishek Actually irrelevant

Comment: instead of `ps.p_id = '3' ` use `ps.p_id = 3` if `p_id` is not `varchar` and remove `where 1=1` from sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify last part of sql:

```
SELECT
cd.family_name,
cd.given_name,
cd.department,
cd.title,
cd.cid,
ps.*, 
company.company_name
FROM contact_details AS cd
LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON cd.cdid = ps.cdid
LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid
WHERE ps.sid IN (25, 22)
AND (company.company_name LIKE '%ab%' 
   OR cd.family_name LIKE '%ab%' 
   OR cd.given_name LIKE '%ab%' )
AND ps.p_id = '3'
GROUP BY cd.cdid
ORDER BY company.company_name ASC
```

Comment: let me try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your OR clauses are expaning your criteria well beyond what you think

I think this is probably what you ment to specify, its a bit of a guess though

```
SELECT
    cd.family_name,
    cd.given_name,
    cd.department,
    cd.title,
    cd.cid,
    ps.*, company.company_name
FROM
    contact_details AS cd
LEFT JOIN project_status AS ps ON cd.cdid = ps.cdid
LEFT JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid
WHERE ps.sid IN (25, 22)
AND company.company_name LIKE '%ab%'
AND (cd.family_name LIKE '%ab%' OR cd.given_name LIKE '%ab%')
AND ps.p_id = '3'
GROUP BY
    cd.cdid
ORDER BY
    company.company_name ASC
```

The `1=1` is totally unnecessary also

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT cd.family_name, cd.given_name, cd.department, cd.title, cd.cid, ps.*, company.company_name 
  FROM contact_details AS cd 
  INNER JOIN project_status AS ps ON cd.cdid = ps.cdid 
  INNER JOIN company ON company.cid = cd.cid 
  WHERE ps.sid IN (25,22) AND ps.p_id = '3' 
  AND ( company.company_name LIKE '%ab%' OR cd.family_name LIKE '%ab%' OR cd.given_name LIKE '%ab%' ) 

  ORDER BY company.company_name ASC
```